# Android open source white noise generator

Tags: android, open-source, audio, offline, noise-generator

I am looking for a noise generator.
Such an app helps me concentrate on work, ignoring conversations around.

Requirements:

- Just white noise, not "cafe noise" or voices or anything recognizable
- Works offline
- Open source
- Runs on Android
- Small (<10 MB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found [Chroma Doze](https://code.google.com/p/chromadoze/). Fits all your requirements. And mine. ;)

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [googlecode.com](https://chromadoze.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/screenshot1.png))</sub>

- Just white noise, not "cafe noise" or voices or anything recognizable
- Works offline
- Open source
- Runs on Android
- Small (<10 MB)

Comment: all requirements? or some?

Comment: All requirements that are listed in the question at the time of writing my answer (and this comment). Or did I miss anything?

Comment: Nope, I just wanted to make sure they were all the requirements. I've edited in the requirements of the question into the answer. If any aren't true, please remove them.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the [White Noise Generator](http://www.appbrain.com/app/white-noise-generator/com.hipxel.white.noise.generator.free) from [Hixpel](http://www.appbrain.com/browse/dev/Hipxel?o=10)

The Operating System is *Android.*

It does not meet your Open source requirement, but may it still helps.

[image][image]

**Pro**

- It is only 0,25 MB Big.
- Nice white noise
- You can use your Volume Control
- Easy to use
- Does not eat to much Battery
- Offline Mode

**Contra**

- Not Open Source
- Using Ads (only on closing screen and no out-of-app ads)

Comment: Does it work offline? (ex: refuses to work if can't load ads)

Comment: It used not to work due to that before the last update, but now its fixed. Im having no problems with Offline mode